# Confidence region for arbitrary multivariate distribution

Tags: multivariate-analysis, confidence-interval

I wonder if there are any publications on computing confidence region for arbitrary multivariate distribution.

So far, I found the following approach: compute confidence interval coordinate vise and take Cartesian product. We will end up with confidence rectangle.

In case of normal distribution we have ellipse and computations are well known, but what do we do in arbitrary multivariate case.

Comment: *Any* textbook on maximum likelihood that addresses distributions with more than one parameter will cover this.

Comment: @whuber, Thank you very much. Could you give me at least one reference to such book. I am new to the field and table of content usually does not fully reveal what is the book.

Comment: Alan Stuart & J. Keith Ord, *Kendall's Advanced Theory of Statistics* (Fifth Edition), Volume 2, chapter 20 (on "Interval Estimation") is a standard reference that contains a brief introduction. They also give a short bibliography of papers by Roy, Roy and Bose, Bartlett, Beale, Halperin, Halperin and Mantel, Bates and Watts, Clarke, Hamilton *et al.*, Cook and Witmer, and Wilks and Daly, published between 1939 and 1985. Other threads on our site also contain references: try [searching](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=book+maximum+likelihood+is%3Aanswer+wiki%3Ayes).